# Count of rows between contiguous on-off signals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 'signal' series with 1 values (on), -1 values (off) and zero values:

```
signal = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1])
```

I need to return the number of rows between contiguous on and off signals, below the result:

first_occurrence = 3

second_occurrence = 2

To take in consideration when two or more contiguous on values are present, the reference is the last one.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards
Tom

Comment: Can you have `1`, followed by `0`, followed by `1` again, and if yes how should that be handled?

Comment: I didn't get it. Why the first occurrence is 3?

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva I think it's the distance between the first 1 and first -1 in this case. Though if you have a 1 followed by another one, the distance is reset and starts at the second 1, which is why the 2nd occurence is 2 and not 3. That's my understanding anyway?

Comment: Yes, correct. It is the distance between the last 1 (before the -1) and -1, so: first occurrence (1,0,0,-1) is 3 and second occurence (1,0,-1) is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the index label from the Series:

```py
s = signal[signal!=0]
np.diff(s[s.shift(-1) != s].index)[::2]
```

Output:

```
array([3, 2])
```

---

**Explanation**

First, remove the zeros:

```
s = signal[signal!=0]
```

Then, remove the consecutive duplicated ones (keeping the last):

```
s = s[s.shift(-1) != s]
```

See the output for understanding what's going on:

```
1    1
4   -1
7    1
9   -1
dtype: int64
```

See that, now we have ones followed by negatives ones, where the original indexes were kept. So we can take the difference in those indexes (and slice for only positive ones):

```
np.diff(s.index)[::2]
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the explanation. In case to have consecutive duplicates -1, how to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

### Basic Solution

The way I would do it is to define several states, like `ON_SIGNAL_SEEN` and `RESET`, and then step through the series, treating things like a state machine. So, as you go through each item, you have different behavior depending the combination of the current state and the current item in the series. Something like (pseudocode):

```
let counter = 0;
let result = [];
let state = RESET
for n in series:
  if state == RESET:
    if n == 1:
      state = ON_SEEN
      counter = 0
  elif state == ON_SEEN
    if n == -1
      counter++
      results += [counter]
      state = RESET
    elif n == 0
      counter++
    elif n == 1
      counter = 0
return result
```

There's also a more object-y way you can do if you define each state as a class and then call `state = state.next(item)`, where the value of state can be either one of the state objects `ON_SEEN`, or `RESET`, each having a different implementation of `next()`.

### Regex Solution

Since regular expressions *are* state machines, I think you could also convert the data to a string and look for an `ab*?c` pattern. Here I've added 2 to all the numbers to avoid having to deal with the `-1` vs `1`(pseudocode again):

```
result = []
//Change the nums from {0,1,-1} to {0,1,2} for easier matching
series = series.add_element_wise(2)

// Change to a string so we can use regex
series_string = (string) series

//Find matches of 2, then 1's, then 0 (with non-greedy matching)
for m in /21*?0/.match(series_string)
  // Save the length of the match
  result += [m.length]
```